# sequence of base64 images to video output file

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, html5-canvas

net MVC4 apps.
  How can I generate video file in my asp.net mvc4 application. I have collection of URLs that are sequence of images in base64 format, generated from canvas output. Please suggest me controller code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the ajax to send the canvas data and the controller code to receive it:

```
// Send the canvas image to the server using ajax
// You can modify this ajax to fit your needs,

var canvas=getElementById("yourCanvas");
var image = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
image = image.replace('data:image/png;base64,', '');

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'yourController/UploadImage',
    data: '{ "imageData" : "' + image + '" }',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(msg){ console.log(msg); }
});


// receive the 64bit encoded string in the controller
// I just convert it to an Image,
// but you can do what you want with the MemoryStream

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UploadImage(string imageData)
{
    byte[] byteArray = System.Convert.FromBase64String(imageData);

    // convert to an image (or do whatever else you need to do)
    Image image;
    using(MemoryStream s=new MemoryStream(byteArray){
        image=Image.FromStream(ms);
    }
    return("done");
}
```